# PowerShell and ADB: How to find the path of a file on the phone

Tags: android, powershell, path, adb

I have a school project with PowerShell and I decided to create a script to backup musics, pictures and videos from the phone (Android only for now) to the PC connected with USB. For that, I'm actually using ADB, wich (I hope it's possible) will be automatically downloaded.

For the moment I have:

```
foreach ($file in .\adb.exe shell ls -R | Where-Object {$_ -match ".mp3" -or $_ -match ".flac" -or $_ -match ".wav"})
{
    echo $file
   .\adb.exe pull -p $cheminFile C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test
}
```

Now what I need is the path of my files on the phone and then I'll be able to copy them with:

```
.\adb.exe pull -p $pathFile C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test
```

How do I get the path? And if you have any advice, I'll be happy to apply them!

Thank you!

Comment: Would `$file in .\adb.exe shell find ./` work? (or `find / `)

Comment: Errr I don't get what is the code. Is it: $pathFile = $file in .\adb.exe shell find ./ ? Because the "in" is unexpected.

Comment: It's a replacement for the code you have which is `$file in .\adb shell ____`. The command `ls -R` is a linux shell command to list files in subfolders with just their name. `find ./` is a linux shell command to list files in subfolders with their full path.

Comment: Thank you so much! 3 days of hard try and it was just that! You saved me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works for me

```
<#
    This powershell script pulls from a USB cable connected android device files to a windows folder.
    If the folder has files in subfolders they will also be copied to a similar subfolder to under the target folder
    The script requires the Android Debug Bridge (adb) available on the windows computer (no installation required)

    Adb Overview
    https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

    Get ADB files
    Download: SDK Platform Tools Release
    https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html#download

    ADB Driver Download  
    I required that driver for the Samsung S7 attached to Windows 7 -> Windows 10 had the driver by default
    https://www.androidpit.de/adb-treiber-android-windows#windowstreiber
    http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

    activate on the android device within the developer options "USB debugging"

    connect the adroid device via USB 

    change the USB connection type to PTP

    check within your android device by the property of a file the path to use

#>

$VerbosePreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$ADBExe = "D:\Android-platform-tools\adb.exe"

cls
. $ADBExe devices

function FN-PullAllFilesFromAnAndroidFolder(){
    param 
        ( [Parameter(mandatory=$true)] [String] $AndroidSourceFolder,
          [Parameter(mandatory=$true)] [String] $WindowsTargetFolder   )

    if ($True){

        $FilesInAndroidFolder = . $ADBExe shell find "'$AndroidSourceFolder'" -type f
        $FilesInAndroidFolder  | Write-Verbose

        if ($True) 
        {
            ForEach ($SingleFileInAndroidFolder in $FilesInAndroidFolder)
            {
                #Replace known characters that are not deliverd correctly by the "adb shell find" query to windows 
                $FileFullPathCodePageFixed = $SingleFileInAndroidFolder.Replace('Ã¤', "ä")
                $FileFullPathCodePageFixed = $FileFullPathCodePageFixed.Replace('Ã„', "Ä") 
                $FileFullPathCodePageFixed = $FileFullPathCodePageFixed.Replace('Ã–', "Ö") 
                $FileFullPathCodePageFixed = $FileFullPathCodePageFixed.Replace('Ãœ', "Ü") 
                $FileFullPathCodePageFixed = $FileFullPathCodePageFixed.Replace('Ã¶', "ö") 
                $FileFullPathCodePageFixed = $FileFullPathCodePageFixed.Replace('Ã¼', "ü")

                $RelativeFullPath = $FileFullPathCodePageFixed.Substring($AndroidSourceFolder.Length - 1, (($FileFullPathCodePageFixed.Length) - $AndroidSourceFolder.Length) + 1)

                if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath (Join-Path -Path $WindowsTargetFolder -ChildPath $RelativeFullPath)))
                {
                    #Check if folder to copy to exists; if not create it
                    $TargetDirectoryWindows = Join-Path -Path $WindowsTargetFolder -ChildPath (Split-Path -LiteralPath $RelativeFullPath)
                    If (! (Test-Path -LiteralPath $TargetDirectoryWindows) ){New-Item -Path $TargetDirectoryWindows -ItemType Directory | Out-Null}

                    #Pull files from android device
                    . $ADBExe pull $FileFullPathCodePageFixed $(Join-Path -Path $WindowsTargetFolder -ChildPath $RelativeFullPath) 

                } Else
                {
                    "Already Backuped: $FileFullPathCodePageFixed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


FN-PullAllFilesFromAnAndroidFolder  -AndroidSourceFolder "/storage/3333-3432/DCIM/CAMERA/" `
                                    -WindowsTargetFolder "D:\Data\Pictures\SamsungS7\"
```